# strftime encoding issue within format string

Tags: php, datetime, encoding, format

I'm trying to format dates using `strftime` and a French locale for `LC_TIME`. I've got an encoding issue, not for the dates themselves but within the format string.

Let me explain ; in my examples, `$format` is `%A %d %B à %Hh%M` and the `$time` date is somewhere in august.

I first started with this : `strftime($format, $time)`, and it gave me `Vendredi 05 Ao�t à 11h57`.

I wanted to solve the encoding problem, so I did this : `utf8_encode(strftime($format, $time))`, which gave me this : `Vendredi 05 Août Ã  11h57`.

You can see that the encoding problem on `août` is gone, but one has appeared on the `à` of the format string.

How may I fix this ? Do I have to do `utf8_encode(strftime("%A %d %B", $time)) . " à " . utf8_encode(strftime("%Hh%M", $time))` or is there a cleaner way ?

Thanks !

Comment: What's your exact locale? What's the character encoding of your file? What's the character set of your HTML output (assuming your output is HTML)? What OS are you using (Linux or Windows or something else)?

Comment: My exact locale is `fr_FR` (`fr_FR.UTF-8` makes no difference here). The encoding of the file is UTF-8, the character set of the HTML is also UTF-8 and I'm on Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the output examples above, I'd guess that your source file is UTF-8 (so the `à` is UTF-8 encoded) and your output HTML is also sent with a UTF-8 character set. The problem seems to be that you're using a non-UTF-8 French locale so the returned string from `strftime()` is **not** UTF-8 but rather something like ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15.

So either you stick with the cumbersome approach of converting only parts of your result string to UTF-8 (`utf8_encode(strftime("%A %d %B", $time)) . " à " . utf8_encode(strftime("%Hh%M", $time))` or you select a UTF-8 variation of the French locale. On Linux that should be something like `fr_FR.UTF-8`.

The following works on Mac OS X (with shipped PHP 5.5):

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.UTF-8');
echo strftime('%A %d %B à %Hh%M', strtotime('2016-08-12 12:00:00'));

// Vendredi 12 août à 12h00
```

Also check the locals supported by your system running `locale -a` on the command line.

Comment: I tried using `fr_FR.UTF-8` with no difference on the issue

Comment: Check the return value of `setlocale()`. If it returns `false` something failed. Different systems have different naming schemes for locales.

Comment: And check the supported locales on your system (`locale -a`)

Comment: `fr_FR.UTF-8` seems to exist as `setlocale(...)` returns `fr_FR.UTF-8`. With the UTF-8 locale the only difference is the double-broken string :`Vendredi 05 AoÃ»t Ã  11h57`

Comment: If you've switched to `fr_FR.UTF-8` you must remove the `utf8_encode()` calls. Your example now seems to be double-encoded.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use the `fr_FR.UTF-8` locale and remove the call to `utf8_encode` as it's no longer necessary.